# ¿Cómo evito que el webhook de whatsapp me mande un mensaje por tiempo indefinido?

Tags: whatsapp

Estoy probando la nueva whatsapp api cloud. Cree la cuenta, configure el endpoint por medio de un tunel de ngrok, luego me suscribí al webhook de mensajes.
Tengo un programa en php que recibe el mensaje que escribe el usuario y lo proceso dependiendo del contenido. Por ejemplo: si el usuario escribe "Hola" le envío una plantilla con el  menú de opciones del chatbot. El problema que tengo es que el webhook me manda el mensaje indefinidamente y, por tanto, el programa de php envía la misma cantidad de veces la plantilla. Verifique y el programa de php devuelve 200, por lo que ese no pareciera ser el problema.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Actualmente, paso por un problema similar, logro solucionar?